# Can't receive all form field values in controller from blade. Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have problem in getting data from blade which have input fields with same name. I am passing 209 combinations of item id, name, unit rate, qty and total value to edit.blade.php. When I try to update the values, I am not getting all the values in controller and getting only 200 array values for item id, name & unit rate and for qty & total I am getting 199 array values.

The another confusing thing is that when I remove one input field from blade (example total) I could receive all 209 array values in my controller. I tried a lot but could not figure out. Please help me to solve this.

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['title' => __('Goods Received')])

@section('content')

    <div class="container-fluid ">

        <div class="row ">
        {!! Form::open(['action' =>['GrnoteController@update', $grnote->id],'method'=>'POST']) !!}
        @method('patch')
        @csrf
            <div class="col-xl-12 order-xl-1">
                <div class="card bg-secondary shadow">
                    <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-8">
                                <h3 class="mb-0">{{ __('Edit GRN') }}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="card-body col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('blnumber') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-blnumber">{{ __('BL Number') }}</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="blnumber" id="input-blnumber" value="{{ $grnote->blnumber }}" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body bg-white border-0 pt-2 pl-3 pb-0">
                            <div class="row align-items-center">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h3 >{{ __('Item Details') }}
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $i=0; ?>
                        @foreach($grn_items as $grn_item)                        
                        <div class="col-md-12 pt-2 stored_items">                            
                            <div class="row">

                                <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="{{$grn_item->id}}">

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="mt-none form-group{{ $errors->has('item') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-item">{{ __('Item Name') }}</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="items[]" id="input-item{{$i}}" value="{{ $grn_item->item }}" required autofocus >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="mt-none form-group{{ $errors->has('rate') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-rate">{{ __('Unit Rate') }}</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="rates[]" id="rate_{{$i}}" step="0.01" value="{{$grn_item->urate}}" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="mt-none form-group{{ $errors->has('qty') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-qty">{{ __('Quantity') }}</label>

                                        <input type="number" name="qtys[]" id="qty_{{$i}}"   value="{{$grn_item->received}}" required  >
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="mt-none form-group{{ $errors->has('total') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                        <label class="form-control-label" for="input-total">{{ __('Total') }}</label>

                                        <input type="text" name="totals[]" id="total_{{$i}}"  placeholder="{{ __('Total') }}" step="0.01" value="{{$grn_item->total}}" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>                        
                        </div>
                        <?php $i = $i+1; ?>
                    @endforeach
                        <div id="group"></div>  
                            <div class="text-right mr-4 pb-3">
                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn1 mt-4" id="btn2" ><i class="ni ni-fat-add"></i></button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pl-5 pr-5 mt-4">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
                                </div>
                        <!-- </form> -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>            
        @include('layouts.footers.auth')
    </div>  
@endsection
```

dd($output) before removing total

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "Yiqq4A3FK6UtVHr4QtCZAUqydUEhYzGc6XT0nU42"
  "_method" => "patch"
  "blnumber" => "MEDUUK332069"
  "ids" => array:200 [▶]
  "items" => array:200 [▶]
  "rates" => array:199 [▶]
  "qtys" => array:199 [▶]
  "totals" => array:199 [▶]
]
```

dd($output) after removing total

```
array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "Yiqq4A3FK6UtVHr4QtCZAUqydUEhYzGc6XT0nU42"
  "_method" => "patch"
  "blnumber" => "MEDUUK332069"
  "ids" => array:209 [▶]
  "items" => array:209 [▶]
  "rates" => array:209 [▶]
  "qtys" => array:209 [▶]
]
```

Comment: Try printing out arrays and check which one is odd and which is missed

Comment: Tried it. It works same if I remove any one of array. Below is the output if I remove qty

Comment: `array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "Yiqq4A3FK6UtVHr4QtCZAUqydUEhYzGc6XT0nU42"
  "_method" => "put"
  "blnumber" => "MEDUUK332069"
  "ids" => array:209 [▶]
  "items" => array:209 [▶]
  "rates" => array:209 [▶]
  "totals" => array:209 [▶]
]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change input limit in `php.ini` file (for Ubuntu /etc/php/{your version}/cli/php.ini):

```
max_input_vars = 20000
```